# How to install TortoiseHG on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, tortoise-hg

I just downloaded and installed the latest Ubuntu and it doesn't look like I’m used to.  I don’t see any Mercurial developer tools in the Ubuntu Software Center.  I got on [the official TortoiseHG site](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/download/index.html) and it looks like it can be done, but I’m not entirely sure how. I’ve done some Googling but the results I keep running into are on older versions of Ubuntu. Any ideas on how I can make this happen?

Comment: Do you know how to install packages via PPA/Launchpad?

Comment: Did you try `sudo apt-get install tortoisehg`? I tried and I could install it. And it's also in [Ubuntu package list](http://packages.ubuntu.com/oneiric/tortoisehg).

Comment: When I install using the command I can't find how to load the application

Comment: Installing only `tortoisehg` makes you able to use it from terminal. To have the GUI of it, you have to install [tortoisehg-nautilus](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/hgtk/wiki/nautilus)..

Comment: @Bibhas - ok, I've done that... when I search my apps for "Tort" I don't see anything

Comment: It wont show up in Application. It is a nautilus extension. Right click on some Directory/empty space in Nautilus file explorer. It should be there.

Comment: @Bibhas Is Nautilus the default file explorer?  I'm newer to Linux so I'm not familiar with that.  I tried right clicking on the file explorer and don't see any Tortoise options.

Comment: Yes. it's the default file explorer. But I think you're out of luck. It seems there is [a bug in nautilus tortoisehg](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/tortoisehg/+bug/859104) that prevents it from running in Ubuntu 11.10(Oneric), as you said Latest Ubuntu, I'm assuming that's what you're using.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Unity or Gnome 3?  TortoiseHg is a Nautilus extension so will only work with Gnome.

There also seems to be issues being reported with TortoiseHg's compatibility with Gnome3:

http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=644697

https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/issue/869/tortoisehg-nautilus-doesnt-work-at-all

Don't know whether these issues have been fixed in the latest version of TortoiseHg.  It might be worth trying with the [TortoiseHg PPA](https://launchpad.net/~tortoisehg-ppa) to get the latest version, as the version that is in the standard Ubuntu repositories tend to lag behind a bit.

---

Update:

There's some info [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/159153/what-happened-to-tortoisehg-nautilus-in-12-04) regarding it working again in 12.10.

Answer (score 0):

The official TortoiseHG site still points to https://launchpad.net/~tortoisehg-ppa
But this PPA is no longer supported, the author has also removed all files from it.
So we have to stick with the old version in official repos, or get the deb from them and update by hand.

Any new PPA manteiner out there?

Comment: This is **not** an answer to the original question. If you have a new question please [ask your own question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) (referencing this one for context if it helps).